# Would it be acceptable to ask "How you are?"

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

The question doesn't sound correct but I'm not sure if it could be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you'll want to stick to the standard sequence, "How are you?"  You might want to visit our sister site for English Language Learners [here.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Although it would be acceptable to ask, "Would it be acceptable to ask how you are?"